# When is the a1 register used for function return in RISC-V

Tags: riscv

In RISC-V, `a0` & `a1` registers hold the function arguments or return values (if any). I've noticed in the generated assembly code that the return value is saved to `a0` register. Is `a0` the default reg for return value, with `a1` being used only when the return value is too big to fit into `a0` alone or there are multiple values returning?

```
#  1 long foo(long a, unsigned long b, char *cp)
#  2 {
#  3   char c = *cp;
#  4   long sum=0;
#  5   long n = a > b ? a-b : b-a;
#  6 
#  7   do {
#  8     sum += n + c;
#  9     n--;
# 10   } while (n > 0);
# 11 
# 12   return sum;
# 13 }


        .file   "example.c"
        .text
        .align  2
        .globl  foo
foo:                            # a0 = a, a1 = b, a2 = cp
        lbu     a5,0(a2)        # a5 = load byte at *c        (=c)
        sub     a4,a1,a0        # a4 = b-a                    (=n, ? false, line 5)
        bleu    a0,a1,.L3       # a < b ? goto .L3
        sub     a4,a0,a1        # a4 = a-b                    (=n, ? true, line 5)
.L3:
        add     a5,a5,a4        # a5 = c + n
        li      a0,0            # a0 = 0                      (=sum, line 4)
.L4:
        add     a0,a0,a5        # a0 += a5 (=c+n)             (line 8)
        addi    a4,a4,-1        # a4--                        (=n--, line 9)
        addi    a5,a5,-1        # a5--                        (=(c+n)--)
        bgt     a4,zero,.L4     # a4(=n) > 0 ? goto .L4
        ret                     # return a0(=sum)
```

The above is the c code and corresponding objdumped risc-v instructions. The `sum` is eventually stored in `a0`, while `a1` is used to hold functional arguments such as `b`. In this case, does the compiler know that for the return value it only needs to look at `a0` register?

If the return value `sum` was much bigger (rather than `long`), and couldn't be fitted into `a0` alone, would the compiler have stored `sum` across both `a0` and `a1`, and refer to both registers for return values?

I was just confused because in the assembly code there is no mention of where the return value is stored at and seemingly everything happens under the hood.

Comment: Let's also add that `a1`is a scratch register so free to be used as desired w/o save & restore, and, we often see compilers using `a1` as a temporary register in computing a single word return value that is being returned in `a0`..  (So, just b/c `a1` is being used doesn't mean it is returning a value to the caller.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the calling convention](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/riscv-calling.pdf), return values that fit in two words or less are placed in a0 and a1.  Implied, but not directly stated is that a0 is used first, so return values that fit in one word will be in a0 and a1 will be unused.